# Plugin Development : How to get previous field value?

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-cde

I'm trying to processing a `step` using my custom `plugin`. so i tried to get the value of a field from previous step inside the method `processRow()`.

i tried some thing like this :

```
public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException {
        meta = (PluginMeta) smi;
        data = (PluginData) sdi;

        Object[] r=getRow();    // get row, blocks when needed!
    if (r==null)  // no more input to be expected...
            {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
            }

        if (first)
            {
                first = false;

                data.outputRowMeta = (RowMetaInterface)getInputRowMeta().clone();
                meta.getFields(data.outputRowMeta, getStepname(), null, null, this);            
            }

        Object[] outputRow = RowDataUtil.addValueData(r, data.outputRowMeta.size()-1, "");

        putRow(data.outputRowMeta, outputRow);     // copy row to possible alternate rowset(s).

        try {
            // Send The Query to ActiveMQ

            FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream("E:\\testing.txt");
            fw.write(fieldSubstitute(meta.getField(), data.outputRowMeta, outputRow).getBytes());
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PluginStep.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@: "+ex.getMessage());
        }
        if (checkFeedback(getLinesRead())) {
            if (log.isBasic()) {
                logBasic("Linenr " + getLinesRead());
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

so i used `fieldSubstitute()` for replacing the field with it's output from previous step as i think that. so i'm confused now because it outputs the field name instead of outputs its value. so i think that i have something wrong with the parameters passed to the method.

so any Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of testing.

I wrote the following inside `ProcessRow()` Method. to fetch the value of fieldname :

```
   Object[] r = getRow();

   // data is my dataClass 
   data.inputRowMeta = getInputRowMeta();

    // meta.getField() is a custom method inside my MetaClass for retrieving name of field
    int indexOfValue = data.inputRowMeta.indexOfValue(environmentSubstitute(meta.getField()));

    // Value of field
    data.inputRowMeta.getString(r, data.indexOfValueField);
```

That's all :)